# How to fix the INSERT statement conflicted with the foreign key constraint when I call ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ef-code-first

I use ajax to create new `Color (id, name)` and `Size (id, name)` and I get their id, quantity in a row to `Quantities` table but checking database, they do not appear and get error.

I got size, color data when I call ajax but when I check SQL Server, it does not have their id.

```
    $("#btnSaveQuantity").on('click', function () {
        var quantityList = [];

        $.each($('#table-quantity-content').find('tr'), function (i, item) {
            var size = $(item).find('input.txtSize').first().val();
            var color = $(item).find('input.txtColor').first().val();
            addColor(color);
            addSize(size);
            var _color;
            var _size;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/admin/Product/GetSize',
                data: {
                    Name: size,
                },
                async: false,
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    _color = data;
                },
                error: function () {
                    osm.notify('Has an error', 'error');
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: '/admin/Product/GetColor',
                data: {
                    Name: color,
                },
                type: 'get',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    _size = data;
                },
                error: function () {
                    osm.notify('Has an error', 'error');
                }
            });
            quantityList.push({
                Id: $(item).data('id'),
                ProductId: $('#hidId').val(),
                Quantity: $(item).find('input.txtQuantity').first().val(),
                SizeId: _size.Id,
                ColorId: _color.Id,
            });
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/Product/SaveQuantities',
            data: {
                productId: $('#hidId').val(),
                quantities: quantityList
            },
            async: false,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                $('#modal-quantity-management').modal('hide');
                $('#table-quantity-content').html('');
            }
        });
    });
```

```js
  function addColor(color) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/Product/AddColor',
            data: {
                Name: color,
            },
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function () {
                osm.notify('Has an error', 'error');
            }
        });
    }
    function addSize(size) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/Product/AddSize',
            data: {
                Name: size,
            },
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function () {
                osm.notify('Has an error', 'error');
            }
        });
    }
```

I expect that database already had recognized colorId and sizeId before I add a new quantity but actually it does not.

Comment: Are the ids an incrementing column, because nothing shows they are sent to the server

Comment: i use method post to add them to database without an id, and I get those obj by name after that by linq. That is what i want to know how it could be like that.